# JS: Why can't I get fonts with JS function in Firefox?

Tags: javascript

```
function getFonts(obj) {
        var o = obj || {},
            sheet = document.styleSheets,
            rule = null,
            i = sheet.length,
            j;
        while(0 <= --i) {
            rule = sheet[i].rules || sheet[i].cssRules || [];
            j = rule.length;
            while(0 <= --j) {
                if(rule[j].constructor.name === 'CSSFontFaceRule') {  
                    o[rule[j].style.fontFamily] = rule[j].style.src;
                };
            }
        }
        return o;
    }
```

It works well on Chrome...
I don't understand why this JS code doesn't work in Firefox...

Comment: My firefox installation gives me **SecurityError: The operation is insecure.** There is nothing syntactically wrong in the code itself, but Firefox obviously refuses to run the function because of some security policy.

Comment: Don't ever use `.constructor.name ===`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

As Bergi as pointed out in his comment and answer, you should not be checking constructor names to distinguish the different [CSSRule types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSRule). Instead, you should use:

```
if (rule[j].type == CSSRule.FONT_FACE_RULE)
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

Some constructor names may be prefixed with `'Moz'`, so instead of:

```
if (rule[j].constructor.name === 'CSSFontFaceRule')
```

You should be checking:

```
if (rule[j].constructor.name.match(/^(Moz)?CSSFontFaceRule$/))
```

So that you match both `'CSSFontFaceRule'` and `MozCSSFontFaceRule`. Also, you might get an error indicating security issues when trying to read `sheet[i].rules` (if the stylesheet has been loaded over HTTPS, for example), so you should add a `try-catch`:

```js
function getFonts(obj) {
  var o = obj || {},
    sheet = document.styleSheets,
    rule = null,
    i = sheet.length,
    j;

  while (0 <= --i) { 
    try {
      rule = sheet[i].rules || sheet[i].cssRules || [];
    } catch(err) {
      console.error(err);
      continue;
    }
    
    j = rule.length;

    while (0 <= --j) {
      if (rule[j].constructor.name.match(/^(Moz)?CSSFontFaceRule$/)) {
        o[rule[j].style.fontFamily] = rule[j].style.src;
      }
    }
  }
  
  return o;
}

console.log(getFonts());
```

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: FontName;
    src: url(font_name.woff);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine">
```

Comment: This regex does not match only "CSSFontFaceRule" or "MozCSSFontFaceRule". It's fixed with `^`, `$` and an optional non-capturing group for the literal "Moz" character-sequence: [`/^(?:Moz)?CSSFontFaceRule$/`](https://regex101.com/r/AnCvp1/1)

Comment: You are right, the regular expression was totally wrong. Just fixed it. Thanks
 

Comment: Using regexes to match the class name is even more horrible.

Comment: @Bergi Dealing with vendor-specific prefixes is horrible, no matter how you do it. Chances are in some other scenario you will have more than one prefix to check, so I think it's better to use a regex than to use multiple `||` to check all of them one by one.

Comment: @Danziger I mean that you never should compare constructor names at all, especially when vendor prefixes further complicate the matter, and that the regex solution makes it even more fragile.

Answer (score 1):

Don't ever compare a `.constructor.name` to figure out the kind of object you are dealing with.

In your particular example, [`CSSRule`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSRule) can and should be distinguished by their `.type`. Replace the `rule[j].constructor.name === 'CSSFontFaceRule'` condition with

```
if(rule[j].type == CSSRule.FONT_FACE_RULE) {
```